# Lorentz Group Exponential Map

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, conventions, lie-algebra

So, I've been trying to derive some of the Lorentz Group properties and one thing got me thinking and I couldn't find any materials that would help me.

If we perform a exponential map $\Lambda = e^{\omega}$ after making some calculations we get to the conclusion that $\omega^{T}\eta = -\eta\omega$; therefore the matrix $\omega$ can be written as the sum of one symmetric matrix and a anti-symmetric matrix such that when we put on index notation what I would expect is $\omega = \omega^{\alpha\beta}M_{\alpha\beta}$, but in reality it seams to be be $\omega = \dfrac{1}{2}\omega^{\alpha\beta}M_{\alpha\beta}$ and I even saw some materials define it as $\omega = \dfrac{i}{2}\omega^{\alpha\beta}M_{\alpha\beta}$.

Why this $\dfrac{1}{2}$ factor come into the equation? why some people define with the $i$ complex number and some don't?

Comment: You are completely comfortable with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Explicit_formulas)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematicians like to define it without the $i$ and physicists like the $i$. If you keep the $i$ in there, then unitarity of a representation $D(\Lambda)$ implies that the corresponding Lie algebra represention $D(M_{\alpha\beta})$ is Hermitian. This is easy to see as
\begin{align}
D(\Lambda)^\dagger &= D ( e^{\frac{i}{2} \omega^{\alpha\beta} M_{\alpha\beta}} )^\dagger = [ e^{\frac{i}{2} \omega^{\alpha\beta} D (  M_{\alpha\beta} ) } ]^\dagger =  e^{- \frac{i}{2} \omega^{\alpha\beta} D (  M_{\alpha\beta} )^\dagger} , \\
D(\Lambda)^{-1} &= e^{- \frac{i}{2} \omega^{\alpha\beta} D (  M_{\alpha\beta} )} 
\end{align}
Then, unitarity $D(\Lambda)^\dagger = D(\Lambda)^{-1}$ implies $D(M_{\alpha\beta})^\dagger = D(M_{\alpha\beta})$ which is the hermiticity condition. In the math convention, $D(M_{\alpha\beta})$ is anti-Hermitian.

The factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ is put in there to ensure that each independent generator appears once in the exponent. For instance, a $2\times2$ antisymmetric matrix has the form
$$
\omega^{\alpha\beta} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \omega^{12} \\ - \omega^{12} & 0 \end{bmatrix} , ~ M_{\alpha\beta} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & M_{12} \\ - M_{12} & 0 \end{bmatrix} \implies  \omega^{\alpha\beta} M_{\alpha\beta} = 2 \omega^{12} M_{12}.
$$
To get rid of the factor of 2 on the RHS, we put in a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in the LHS. Generalizing to 4 dimensions, we find
$$
\frac{1}{2} \omega^{\alpha\beta} M_{\alpha\beta} = \omega^{01} M_{01} + \omega^{02} M_{02} + \omega^{03} M_{03} + \omega^{12} M_{12} + \omega^{23} M_{23} + \omega^{13} M_{13} . 
$$

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me!